# StartExecPost calling the service itself

Tags: linux, systemd, service, systemctl

I have a service defined as bellow:

```
Unit]
Description=My Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPost=/usr/local/bin/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and `script.sh` contains commands like:

```
while ! $(systemctl is-active --quiet myservice) ; do echo "waiting.."; sleep 5; done
```

(and other calls to the service)

The problem is that it doesn't work.
I think it's a chicken-and-egg issue. I'm waiting for the service to be up in the service start itself. This obviously can't work.

So my question is:

How can I run `script.sh` automatically when myservice is up?

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to use `ExecStartPost` with a service that doesn't play nice since it doesn't notify systemd when it has finished starting up, you're most likely stuck with trying whatever it is you need `ExecStartPost` until it works.

Answer (score 0):

From manual

> ExecStartPost= commands are only run after the commands specified in
> ExecStart= have been invoked successfully, as determined by Type=
> (i.e. the process has been started for Type=simple or Type=idle, the
> last ExecStart= process exited successfully for Type=oneshot, the
> initial process exited successfully for Type=forking, "READY=1" is
> sent for Type=notify/Type=notify-reload, or the BusName= has been
> taken for Type=dbus).

So ExecStartPost will executed only after `ExecStart= have been invoked successfully`.

Your script doesn't work may be due to wrong options choose in unit file.

Comment: I investigated a bit more. Actually, having service in `running` state is not enough. The service needs to start a server and listen on port X. This can take a bit of time. Thus, ExecStartPost starts too quickly, before the server to be started. What I don't understand is that I tool this in account in my script.sh (wait for port to be open) but it's waiting forever